# Unity PlayPrefs not working on Windows: PlayerPrefsException: Could not store preference value at UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs.SetString

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just launched my game on Steam and we're getting bug reports. Upon checking the log, I found this error:

PlayerPrefsException: Could not store preference value
at UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs.SetString

There's no other additional details. This occurs on Windows. Any ideas?

Comment: This forum post is saying that there is a 1mb limit to what can be written tot he player prefs might that maybe be the case? https://forum.unity.com/threads/exception-calling-playerprefs-set-method.408848/ . Unfortunately they didn't update the answer with the eventual solution.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when I removed the parent key while the game was running in the editor. Try restarting the game and/or Unity and see if it helps.